# BlazeMeter Chrome Extension - How to identify the Parallel requests

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I have recorded a test via Chrome extension. How do I identify the Parallel and Simultaneous requests here?

Is there a way to figure this out? Am unable to find the request start times as well.

Please help. Thanks for your support.

Note: F12 Developer Tools also doesn't display the request start times.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests which are started at the same time are parallel, like red rectangle in the below image of the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

[image]

others are sequential.

When it comes to BlazeMeter Chrome Extension the default configuration is:

[image]

1. Record Top Level Requests which means don't record images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc. and let JMeter's HTTP Request sampler to do this in parallel. Don't forget to add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to represent the browser's cache as real browsers download embedded resources only once.

   More information: [JMeter Web Testing: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter)
2. [AJAX Requests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp). These are recorded sequentially however you can identify them by using `XHR` filter in browser developer tools, these requests should go under the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller)